# Images do not appear on the site nor the iphone iOS tablet

Tags: php, ios, web, image-scaling

On site: http://viladivanomoveis.com.br/?page=produtos&prod=Poltronas Images are not displayed when accessing from iphones or ipads, suspect it is because of this php code which resizes the original picture:

```
<a href="?page=item&prod=<?php echo remover($exeprod['produto']);?>">
 <img src="thumb.php?img=admin/<?php echo $spr[0];?>&x=300&y=300&q=80" alt="" title=""/>
</a>
```

Anyone knows how to to make the images appear?

Answer (score 0):

Looking @ http://viladivanomoveis.com.br/?page=produtos&prod=Poltronas and your code this won't be affecting your images.

The PHP code is done on the server regardless of the device used and doesn't resize it.

I would assume this is to do with your style sheet(CSS).